# Why Qemu console is buggy?

Tags: qemu

I have Linux Neon host system and QEMU aarm64 emulator with Debian 11 installed on it. The Debian 11 console works bad: sometimes it loses row and jump up.

Sometimes unable to perform "<-" move cursor back inside command line. Sometimes another bugs which make impossible to work with command line in Debian 11 console.

Please see the following video

https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/765214245

Please help me to fix qemu to avoid such problems with CLI?

**UPD:** QEMU runs locally inside Terminal Emulator https://konsole.kde.org/ using this command

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -machine virt,gic-version=max -m 3G -cpu max -smp 4 \
-netdev user,id=vnet,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:0-:22 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vnet \
-net nic -net user,smb=/home/katya/work/prostor/ \
-drive file=ubuntu-image.img,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0,bootindex=0 \
-drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash
```

Comment: You should show how exactly you connect to the console. There are few different ways to setup a QEMU console and connect to it.

Comment: @aviro Please take a look to update of question